# Advanced Filter, Does Not Contain

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a very long column of three-character combinations of alphanumeric and dash characters. Below is a very small sample of the data.

[image: ![enter image description here]

**How do you filter this column, so that any cell or combination that contains a number or dash is removed or hidden?**

I have tried looking everywhere online for a solution, but cannot find anything other than it has something to do with Excel's Advanced Filter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Advanced Filter` with a formula criteria.

If your list starts in `A4` (with the data start in `A5`), then the formula would be:

```
=MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"-"},A5&"0123456789-"))>LEN(A5)
```

This will return `TRUE` if digits or the dash are not found in the cell

Suggest you read about using Formulas for criteria in the Advanced Filter Help material. Note that the formula criteria **cannot** be in row 1 of your criteria range.  In row 1 you must have a label that is **NOT** the same as any of your column labels, or it can be blank.

**Before**

[image]

**Filter Dialog**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: ok thanks. i will have to read about using formulas in the Advanced Filter because im a total n00b when it comes to Excel

Comment: this would be so easy to do in a browser, although somewhat time consuming to set-up a database